# GitHub: Any way to use relative links from Wiki to a file in the repo?

Tags: github, hyperlink, markdown, relative-path

I'm working on the wiki inside our GitHub and would like to use shorter links to link to a file in the repo. I've found that if I use the normal relative link method as described [here](https://github.com/blog/1395-relative-links-in-markup-files), the link is relative to the wiki, i.e. it tries to find a page in the wiki with that name, whereas the relative links described in GitHubs docs and blog are assuming that the link is in the README.

Is there a way to use shortened links from the wiki to files in the repo or do I have to use the full link?

Answer (score 11):

Try [this one](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#links):

```
[I'm a relative reference to a repository file](../blob/master/LICENSE)
```